# Scraping adf faces oracle rich client

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, rich-client-platform

I am trying to scrape a oracle adf faces rich client webpage but I am not getting the best of luck, I login automatically using node.js request module but after that I can't get to any other page with request. I get stuck on redirects, the loop script or simply don't get information I expect to.

I am using Wireshark to view every page and the way it handles, I recreate the page to match headers and even size but everytime the framework denies me access.

Before you ask, it's legal and I am not breaking any terms of service. Just trying to make a web api to speed up a process. I have used phantomjs with casperjs but get stuck on ajax calls that don't show on page and php curl but it's much easier with java.

Any suggestions are really really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad on this one, wireshark was displaying fields as truncated, if you want to see the full field you need to right click the packet and click follow TCP stream, rich clients have very long posts generated by the framework behind the rich client and it appears I was missing about half of them when I did the calls.